# Save and open dictionary

Tags: python

I saved a dictionary to a txt file using this code

```
dic = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
f = open("dict.txt","w")
f.write( str(dic) )
f.close()
```

Now I am wondering how I can import it again into a dictionary?

Comment: use the `ast` module --> `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: @Rakesh How exacrtly would you use it here `?

Comment: @james what about reading the doc and trying by yourself in your python shell?

Comment: Use a format designed for serialisation, not just the repr - if your data is this simple, I'd suggest JSON.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like to save the results onto a hard drive for long time storage. This is why I chose txt. I don't quite understand json good enough to apply it yet.

Comment: JSON is just a flat text format, you can store it in a text file on a hard drive just fine. It's also more human readable and more accessible to other languages than a pickle.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) the `dict` if you want to read it again.

```
import pickle

dic = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(dic, handle)
```

To read from pickle

```
import pickle

with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    read_dict = pickle.load(handle)
print(read_dict)
```

Otherwise in this scenario you can do this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> f = open("dict.txt","r")
>>> ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you !! How do you pickle it ? I would like to save the results onto a hard drive for long time storage. This is why I chose txt. Does it also work with pickle ? How would you do it.

Comment: @james updated, please go through the documentation and read it for better understanding

Comment: sorry, forgot about that. :)